# Implementing run time polymorphism and inheritence

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, ios

What is the equivalent concept of interface in java in objective C. I want to create a interface and define some common variables and methods which will be shared by many classes inheriting from my interface. When any class outside want to use a child class it will get a reference object of my interface which will point to correct child class.

How to achieve this in Objective C?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An Objective C equivalent of Java interfaces is called "[protocol](http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html#protocols)".

A small intro can also be found [here](http://mauvilasoftware.com/iphone_software_development/2008/05/a-brief-intro-to-objective-c-p.html), and if you want a full reference, it's [at Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProtocols.html)

Answer (score 5):

In Objective-C, you can achieve this by making use of [Protocols](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProtocols.html).  A protocol is basically the precursor to an interface in Java, so most of the behavior should come naturally.

A protocol declaration looks like the following:

```
@protocol Foo
-(void) foo;
-(int) boo: (int) arg;
@end
```

It may be implemented by a class.  In the following case, you would say MyClass conforms to the Foo protocol.

```
@interface MyClass <Foo>
{
}

@end

@implementation MyClass

-(void) foo {
    //do something
}
-(int) boo: (int) arg {
    //do something else
    return arg;
}

@end
```

Finally, you can pass them around like this:

```
-(void) someMethod: (id<Foo>) arg;
```

If you need to be more specific about the object, they can also be used like this:

```
-(void) someMethod: (NSObject<Foo> *) arg;
```